# Consulta SQL en un sistema de gestión

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día,

Estoy construyendo un sistema de gestión interna para un estudio contable, el cual tiene varios módulos, entre ellos: CONTACTOS y CLIENTES.

El sistema en general, funciona como una gran agenda de CONTACTOS que no necesariamente son CLIENTES del estudio, por lo cual, solo están cargado sus datos en el módulo de contacto.

El problema radica en la siguiente consulta SQL de mi módulo de clientes: un contacto puede ser accionista de una empresa juridica. Esta consulta funciona bien si los dos contactos juridicos a referenciar son CLIENTES, es decir, que ya se le haya asignado un ID CLIENTE a los dos, por lo cual, si agrego un contacto que solo está en el módulo de contactos, la consulta no se cumple ya que no tiene un ID cliente al cual buscar.

Como puedo corregir este problema?

Anexo código y las tablas en la base de datos:

INSERT de accionista:

```
 cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

        if (var_accion_det_accionistas == "insert")
        {

            myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

            //Asignamos el mysqlcommand la conexion datos
            mysqlcommand_insert.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

            campos = "";
            valores = "";

            campos = "IdCliente,";
            valores = "'" + txt_cod_cliente.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "IdContactoAccionista,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_cod_cbo_accionista.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "Acciones,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_acciones.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "Porcentaje,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_porct.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "ValorNominal,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_valor_nominal.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "Capital,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_capital.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "NroVotos,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_num_votos.Text + "',";

            if (var_fecha_adquisicion == "")
            {
                campos = campos + "FechaDeAsuncion";
                valores = valores + "'" + dtp_fecha_adquisicion.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'";

            }


            mysqlcommand_insert.CommandText = "insert into Accionistas (" + campos + ") VALUES (" + valores + ")";

            mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteReader();

            myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();


            // PROCESO AL INVERSA PARA INDICAR A CUAL EMPRESA SOY ACCIONISTA
            var_IdCliente_relac_accionista_de = buscar_cliente(txt_cod_cbo_accionista.Text);


            myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

            //Asignamos el mysqlcommand la conexion datos
            mysqlcommand_insert.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

            campos = "";
            valores = "";

            campos = "IdCliente,";
            valores = "'" + var_IdCliente_relac_accionista_de + "',";
            campos = campos + "IdContactoAccionista,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_cod_contacto_clie.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "Acciones,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_acciones.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "Porcentaje,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_porct.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "ValorNominal,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_valor_nominal.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "Capital,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_capital.Text + "',";
            campos = campos + "NroVotos,";
            valores = valores + "'" + txt_num_votos.Text + "',";

            if (var_fecha_adquisicion == "")
            {
                campos = campos + "FechaDeAsuncion";
                valores = valores + "'" + dtp_fecha_adquisicion.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'";

            }

            mysqlcommand_insert.CommandText = "insert into AccionistaEmpresas (" + campos + ") VALUES (" + valores + ")";

            mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteReader();

            myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

--ESTO FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE --

-- CONSULTA SQL QUE SOLO FUNCIONA SI LOS DOS CONTACTOS JURIDICOS TIENEN UN ID CLIENTE

```
if (cbo_tipo_contacto.Text == "Jurídico")
        {
            try
            {

                //Instanciamos la clase
                cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

                myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

                //Asignamos el mysqlcommand la conexion datos
                mysqlcommand_select.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;


                strSQL = " select acce.IdAccionista, acce.IdCliente AS Cliente, acce.IdContactoAccionista,con.RazonSocial AS [Razón Social], " +
                         "  acce.Acciones, acce.Porcentaje,acce.ValorNominal,acce.Capital,acce.NroVotos,acce.FechaDeAsuncion " +
                           " from AccionistaEmpresas AS acce " +
                          " Left outer JOIN Contactos AS con " +
                             " on acce.IdContactoAccionista = con.IdContacto " +
                          "  WHERE acce.IdCliente=" + txt_cod_cliente.Text + "";


                myDataAdapter_Accionistade = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myCls_general.myConnection);
                myDataSet_Accionistade = new DataSet();
                myDataAdapter_Accionistade.Fill(myDataSet_Accionistade, "AccionistaEmpresas");

                dgv_list_acc.DataSource = myDataSet_Accionistade;
                dgv_list_acc.DataMember = "AccionistaEmpresas";
                dgv_list_acc.Refresh();

                myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();

                //if (dgv_list_acc.Rows.Count > 0)
                //{

                //    armar_grid_accionista_empresa();

                //}

                armar_grid_accionista_empresa();

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        else

        {

            try
            {

                //Instanciamos la clase
                cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

                myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

                //Asignamos el mysqlcommand la conexion datos
                mysqlcommand_select.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;


                strSQL = " SELECT  Clientes.IdCliente AS Cliente, Clientes.IdContacto AS Contacto, Contactos.RazonSocial AS [Razón Social], " +
                         "  Accionistas.Acciones, Accionistas.Porcentaje,Accionistas.ValorNominal,Accionistas.Capital,Accionistas.NroVotos,Accionistas.FechaDeAsuncion " +
                           " FROM  Clientes " +
                          " INNER JOIN Contactos " +
                             " ON Clientes.IdContacto = Contactos.IdContacto " +
                          " INNER JOIN Accionistas " +
                             " ON Clientes.IdCliente = Accionistas.IdCliente " +
                          "  WHERE        IdContactoAccionista=" + txt_cod_contacto_clie.Text + "";
```

Comment: Creo que deberias centrar tu consulta a solo la parte del sql. Lo que pasa en el programa no incide en tu problema en la base de datos. Yo reescribiria toda la pregunta, centrado en ese tema. Asi como esta, confunde mas.. Lo que hace falta son las tablas, datos y la consulta que no funciona. Mira por favor [ask] y de paso hace el [tour]

Comment: Por todo lo que comentas, tu query no puede andar nunca en la base de datos..

Comment: La consulta funciona perfectamente si los dos contactos a relacionar son clientes. Ahí se ven los datos perfecto! El tema está en que si uno es cliente y el otro solo contacto ahí no funciona. Entonces mi consulta es que puedo hacer para que cuando no sea cliente, se relacione de alguna forma con ese contacto y muestre la informacion.

Comment: por eso mismo, te falta una consulta cuando esa condicion no se cumple. tu consulta no anda!